How to add jars to a pyspark interpreter in Zeppelin
Got a working standalone PySpark script that reads a local delta file and creates a table on top of it for querying.
Asked to move it to a zeppelin notebook so as to run on AWS infrastructure.
The zeppelin script goes into endless execution and eventually times out. I suspect it has to something with the delta jars declaration.
Any idea on how to create a working spark context like the one in standalone script.
Getting anything installed on AWS is kinda tricky, so would like the Zeppelin script to be as much self-contained as possible.
Thanks
Standalone script
import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkFiles
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

from delta import *
from delta.tables import *

import sys

spark = (
    SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]")
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "io.delta:delta-spark_2.12:3.2.0")
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")
    .getOrCreate()
)
....
....
....

#Load delta file into DataFrame
deltadf = spark.read.format("delta").load(s3://delta_table_path)

deltadf.createOrReplaceTempView("tempEmployee")

df = spark.sql("SELECT count(*) FROM tempEmployee")

Zeppelin
%spark.pyspark**

spark.jars="io.delta:delta-spark_2.12:3.2.0"

....
....
....

#Load delta file into DataFrame
deltadf = spark.read.format("delta").load(delta_table_path)

deltadf.createOrReplaceTempView("tempEmployee")

df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT count(*) FROM tempEmployee")

